# Django change base template based on user authenticaton

Tags: django, authentication, django-templates

I have two base templates: base.html and base_visitor.html. I want base.html to be extended if user is authenticated and base_vistior.html if user is not authenticated. I have already tried this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% else %}
  {% extends 'base_visitor.html' %}
{% endif %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<h1>Title</h1>

{% if models %}
  {% for model in models %}
  <h2>{{ model.model_number }}<h2>
  {% endfor %}


{% else %}
<h3>NO models</h3>

{% endif %}





{% endblock %}
```

But for some reason this gives me an error: "Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot put the `extends` tag in `if`/`else` blocks.

You can however use a variable for the template parameter, example:

```
{% extends base_template_name %}
```

If you want this mechanism to be applied globally, the best place to define such a variable would be in a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext), ex:

```
def base_template_name_context_processor(request):
    # Use request.user.is_authenticated() if using Django < 2.0
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        base_template_name = 'base.html'
    else:
        base_template_name = 'base_visitor.html'

    return {
        'base_template_name': base_template_name,
    }
```

To plug this context processor to the template engine, check the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: that's terrific! great idea

Comment: Got slightly consused by an error until I realized `request.user.is_authenticated` is an attribute and not a method, so should not have parentheses afterwards.

Comment: @wjakobw yes they changed that in Django 2.0